# AMP - Phone Number Loses Font Color

Tags: html, css, accelerated-mobile-page

I've created an 'Accelerated Mobile Page' with no issue other than losing the 'Color' of a phone number, or any 10-digit+ combination.

```
<style>
h3{
color: white;
text-shadow:1.5px 1.5px grey;
text-align: center;
background-color: #39bf4a;
padding: 5px;
}
</style>

<h3>Call us today at 555-555-5555</h3>
```

Less than 10 digits = okay;

10+ digits = loses color of font (adopts background color)

I'm assuming it has something to do with the recognition of a phone number, but haven't been able to find anything within the documentation outlining this.

I will continue to dig, but if anyone has ran into this issue and has an answer, it'd help a ton!

Thank you.

Comment: What is this: <h3>Call us today at 555-555-5555</h3>? Is its value fixed? If not how it will change?

Comment: Yes, the value is fixed. 555-555-5555 loses its style and for testing purposes, I removed 1 digit, making it 555-555-555 and the styling is applied again. The text "Call us today at" remains unchanged either way. I'm assuming it has something to do with the character encoding? Looks fine on desktop, but not on mobile.

Comment: Please remove your text-shadow and test again.

Comment: Just tried - didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It is an strange behavior in safari that count the '555-555-5555' as a link!

If you add this style it will work as you want:

```
 h3 a{
    color: white;
    text-shadow:1.5px 1.5px grey;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #39bf4a;
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
```

}

The only bad (maybe not wrong) in your code is the text-shadow. Text-shadow has a syntax like this:

px px px color.

Comment: You are correct in your understanding of the question. I am using an iPhone 6 with the latest version of Safari and iOS. I agree it is a browser issue.